# ExpressJs 4.0 new Router - How to handle paramters

Tags: express

**Unless I am mistaken, this is the proper approach to using the new ExpressJs 4.0 router:**

```
'use strict';
 var express = require('express'),
    fooCtrl = require ('./controllers/fooCtrl'),
    router = express.Router();

    module.exports = function(app){
       router.route('/foo')
        .get(fooCtrl.getAll),
        .post(fooCtrl.post);

     .....

       app.use('/foo', router);
   }
```

But how do you handle ***.put, .get(by id) and .delete where an id is needed***?

If I did not use router.route above, it would be:

```
    .get('/foo/:id, fooCtrl.getById),
    .put('/foo/:id, fooCtrl.update),
    .delete('/foo/:id, fooCtrl.delete);
```

So would I handle .get(by id), .put and .delete when I use router.route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer on [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

> ```
> router.route('/users/:user_id') 
>    .all(...),
>    .get(...),
>    .put(...),
>    .post(...),
>    .delete(...)
> ```

Apparently you put '/:id' in the route parameter for all.